# If $f$ is a contraction, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to solve this question.

> Let $0\leq \lambda \lt 1$ and $f:X\subset\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a
>   $\lambda$-contraction, i.e., $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \lambda |x-y|$ for any
>   $x,y \in X$. Prove that if $X$ contains a closed interval $[a-r,a+r]$
>   and $|f(a)-a|\leq (1-\lambda)r$, then $f$ has a fixed point in
>   $[a-r,a+r]$.

In order to begin to solve this question, I'm trying to prove that this function is derivable, I need help, particularly in this part.

thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you want to prove that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: 1) Prove that if there is a fixed point, then it is unique. 2) Prove that there exists a fixed point by taking an arbitrary $x_0$ in $[a-r,a+r]$ and defining by induction $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. You will prove easily that $x_n$ converges to a fixed point.

Comment: @julien but in order to prove that I have to prove first the differenciability of the function, no?

Answer (score 3):

If the contraction $f$ is defined all over $\mathbb{R}$, then by [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) $f$ will have a fixed point, which can be obtained as the limit point of $x_{0} = a$, $x_{i+1} = f(x_{i})$. (That is, $x_{n} = f^{n}(a)$.)

Now $f$ is only defined over $X$. But the second condition guarantees that the sequence $(x_i)$ is all contained in $[a-r,a+r]$, so you are done.

To see this, first prove by induction that
$$
\lvert f^{n+1}(a) - f^{n}(a)\rvert
\le
\lambda^{n} (1-\lambda) r,
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align}
\lvert f^{n+1}(a) - a\rvert
&\le
\lvert f^{n+1}(a) - f^{n}(a)\rvert + \lvert f^{n}(a) - f^{n-1}(a)\rvert
+ \dots + \lvert f(a) - a\rvert
\\&\le
(\lambda^{n} + \lambda^{n-1} + \dots + \lambda + 1) (1 - \lambda) r = (1 - \lambda^{n+1}) r < r.
\end{align}$$

Comment: but to use this we have to prove the differentiability of $f$, no? when I proved this fixed-point theorem, I used a fact that the differentiability of $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @user42912, no, you just need $f$ to be a contraction. (See the Wikipedia reference.) You are probably thinking of the converse implication.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti It might be too late for such a question, but how the condition $|f(a)-a|\le r$ implies that the sequence is all in $[a-r,a+r]$? We need to have $|f(x)-a|<r \ \forall x\in [a+r,a-r]$, no?

Comment: @Daniil, I believe my original answer stands on its feet, as we are only concerned with the values of the sequence. In any case, the argument for what you ask is the following. Let $\lvert x - a \rvert \le r$. Then $\lvert f(x) - a \rvert = \lvert f(x) - f(a) + f(a) - a \rvert \le \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert + \lvert  + f(a) - a \rvert \le \lambda \lvert x - a \rvert + (1 - \lambda) r \le \lambda r + (1 - \lambda) r = r$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Nice thank you!